# Is this convex minimizer a continuous function?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the function $g: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by:
$$
g(x) = \arg\min_{y\in\mathbb R} \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(|y - x_i|)
$$
where $f_i$ are convex, strictly increasing and continuous. Further assume that at least one $f_i$ is strictly convex (so the minimizer is unique). Is $g$ a continuous function?

Comment: I would start with the case $n=1$.  How would you treat the situation in which the functions $f_i$ do not have unique minimums?

Comment: Just because the functions $f$ are convex does not mean their composition with absolute values will be.

Comment: Updated the question with more conditions on $f_i$'s. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

As you've written it, $g(x)$ appears to be a set valued function: the minimum can occur at many values of $y$. For instance, when each $f_i$ is constant we have $f(x)=\mathbb R$ for any value of $x$.

Comment: Updated the question with more conditions on $f_i$'s. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer...